# Como fazer o optgroup acessar uma página

Tags: javascript, html, html-option, selected-option

Tenho um código e eu quero que ele funcione da seguinte forma:
Eu criei uma lista de `options` dentro de um `optgroup` e quero que assim que eu clicar em uma opção, ele ir pra página que eu quero.

Exemplo:

```
<optgroup>
<option>Opcao1</option>
<option>Opcao2</option>
<option>Opcao3</option>
</optgroup>
```

E assim que clicasse na opção 2, por exemplo, ele acessaria a seguinte url: `www.site.com/lista/Opcao2/index.html`

Então o padrão seria: `www.site.com/lista/(opção escolhida)/index.html`

Atualmente o código está assim (por enquanto): 
[image]

E no site está assim: 
[image]

Teria alguma forma sem utilizar php?

Comment: O optgroup tem informação para o link? ou só o option? Como estás a gerar esse html? no servidor ou browser?

Comment: @Sergio eu to fazendo um site de notícias sobre séries, então o código tá assim (por enquanto): http://prntscr.com/fv007a
E no site tá assim: http://prntscr.com/fv00em

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que seja algo interpretado no clique é necessário escutar o evento `onchange` da etiqueta `<select>`,e quando acontece mudamos de *url* modificando o `window.location.href`:

Exemplo:

```js
document.getElementById("cEst").onchange=function(){ 
  //this.value tem o valor que foi escolhido nas opções
  window.location.href = "www.site.com/lista/" + this.value + "/index.html"; 
}
```

```html
<select name="tEst" id="cEst">
  <optgroup>
    <option>Opcao1</option>
    <option>Opcao2</option>
    <option>Opcao3</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Aconselho a ter cuidado com os espaços no *url* pois eles são convertidos para outros caracteres (normalmente + ou %20) e por esse motivo pode não funcionar.

Comment: Coloque o `<script>` no fim da etiqueta `<body>`